# How to show that $\int_0^1x^{-x}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, summation, numerical-methods

How would I go about showing that $\int_0^1x^{-x}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-n}$

Right now my numerical analysis class is covering gaussian quadrature but we have also covered interpolation. I'm not sure how to prove this equality without using an estimation for the lefthand integral

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836147/sophomores-dream-displaystyle-int-01-x-x-dx-sum-n-1-infty-n

Comment: This is known as [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). See this for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237513/series-as-an-integral-sophomores-dream. The first link (Wikipedia) also has a proof section.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y=-\ln x$ so the integral becomes $$\int_0^1\exp(-x\ln x)dx=\sum_{m\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\int_0^1 x^m\ln^m xdx\\=\sum_{m\ge 0}\frac{1}{m!}\int_0^\infty y^m\exp[-(m+1)y] dy=\sum_{m\ge 0}\frac{1}{(m+1)^{m+1}}.$$